# Thai language wrongly displayed:

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, thai, southeast-asian-languages

I have a file `notfound.php` which returns a list of available keywords in English and Thai.
It contains

`meta http-equiv='Content-Type content='text/html; charset=tis-620'".`

Thai Language displays properly if I request the page using any of the browsers I have, where outputs Thai wrongly when calling the same file using JavaScript.

```
document.getElementById("area").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
xmlhttp.open("GET","notfound.php?&mat=" + Math.random(),true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

This fragment is from a file also containing

`meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=tis-620`'.

The text returned to "area" displays correctly only in Chrome.

Comment: > "outputs Thai wrongly"
What does it output? What should it output? I'm guessing it's an encoding issue.

Comment: ������ rather then ภาษาไทย 
yes, an encoding issue which arise only using  xmlhttp

Comment: Can't you change it to return `utf-8` instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
function sendByAJAX() {
   // get the user text and make it safe for HTTP transmission
   var userTxt = encodeURIComponent( document.getElementById('userTxt').value );
   // create the AJAX object
   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   // assume successful response -- do NOT actually make this assumption in real code
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status>=200 && xmlhttp.status<300) {
         // You'll probably want to do something more meaningful than an alert dialog
         alert('POST Reply returned: status=[' + xmlhttp.status + 
        ' ' + xmlhttp.statusText + ']\n\nPage data:\n' + xmlhttp.responseText);
      }
   }
   xmlhttp.open('POST', 'http://www.site.com/submit/path');
   // here we are overriding the default AJAX type, 
   // which is UTF-8 -- this probably seems like a stupid thing to do
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 
    'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=tis-620;');
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('User-agent'  , 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible) Naruki');
   xmlhttp.send(userTxt);
}
```

Comment: changed get to post as for you suggested. Same: correct only in Chrome

Comment: I have tried  xmlhttp.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=tis-620").It works in most browser,and thai text is now correct,but does not work in IE9 which complains 'overrideMimeType not a property of this object.

Comment: Spent the whole afternoon on this one. To make xmlhttp display Thai language correctly all request to server (GET/POST never mind) must have a php header in the requested file: 
header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=tis-620") at the very top line after the <?php tag.

html tag meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=tis-620" did not work for me.

When querying a database  mysql_query("set names 'tis620'") is mandatory. Alleluia